# How to write a function which will be treated as a service in react to add products to the cart

Tags: reactjs

Each product has a add to cart button, whenever it is clicked that product gets added to the cart. The cart is shown as a drawer that pops from right and shows all the products that we added.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far? Need some code so we can help you.

Comment: Can you check this detailed question with code, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70687189/how-to-push-the-product-data-to-data-layer-in-react

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `Context` api with custom hook to manage cart or you can use `Redux` for this

Comment: can you check this detailed question with code, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70687189/how-to-push-the-product-data-to-data-layer-in-react