# How to push the product data to data layer in REACT?

Tags: reactjs

I have multiple products on a page with an add to cart button next to each, my ultimate goal is to achieve a checkout page. First step is to push the product data to data layer. My data is coming from a Firebase database.

This is my reducer:

```
export const initialState = {
    basket: [],
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    console.log(action);
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TO_BASKET':
            return {
                ...state,
                basket: [...state.basket, action.item],
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default reducer;
```

This is the state provider:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";

export const StateContext = createContext();


export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }
) => (
    <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)
    }
    >
        {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
);

export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

And this is where I need help to write the dispatch code, my current code is throwing errors in item:

```
import React, { MouseEventHandler } from "react";
import "./product.scss";
import placeholder from "./../../../../assets/images/productPlaceholder.jpg";
import { AdvertiseStoreProduct } from "../../../../models/AdvertiseStore/advertiseStore.model";
import { privateDecrypt } from "crypto";
import { useStateValue } from '../../../../StateProvider';
interface ProductProps {
  index: number;
  clicked: MouseEventHandler;
  product: AdvertiseStoreProduct;
}

const Product = (props: ProductProps) => {
  const { product, clicked, index } = props;

  const [state, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  
    const addToBasket = () => {
    //dispatch product to data layer
    dispatch({
      type: 'ADD_TO_BASKET',
      item: {
        product.id: product.id,
        product.name: product.name,
        product.price: product.price,
      },
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="product-card" onClick={clicked}>
      <div className="product-card-image">
        <img
          src={product.imageUrl || placeholder}
          alt={product.name}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="product-card__details">
        <h5 className="product-card--name">{product.name}</h5>

        <p className="product-card--price"> ₹ {product.price}</p>
        <div><button onClick={addToBasket}>Add to cart</button></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the way you are assigning object is wrong.

```
item: {
"keyName": value
}
```

or u want a dynamic key name
use

```
item: {
[variableName]:  value
}
```

---

dispatch({
type: 'ADD_TO_BASKET',
item: {

**(wrongkey)  product.id**: product.id,
product.name: product.name,
product.price: product.price,
},
});

Comment: thanks a lot that was on spot, I was struggling since a while

Answer (score -1):

```
item: {
        product.id: product.id,
        product.name: product.name,
        product.price: product.price,
      },
```

change this to below code

```
item:{
       id=id,
        title:title,
        image:image,
        price:price,
        rating:rating,
      },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).